# Can last names be shortened just as first names?

Tags: names

I know first names are usually shortened in verbal communication for reasons that I am not clear about. For example, *Andrew* becomes *Andy*.

But is it also the case for last names? If yes, what is the reason? Is it polite or impolite? For example, if I am correct, I heard once that *Robinson* is shortened to *Robin* by a third person in the US.

Comment: No, but you can always fall back on:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_nicknames_used_by_George_W._Bush

Comment: A cultural note (and thus not on-topic for this site): Referring to someone by a nickname or shortened name is impolite if that person doesn't appreciate it. Names are very personal. And a communication note: a nickname only works if everyone knows it. First names often have well-known and predictable short forms, but last names are not commonly shortened in this way.

Comment: @Mr. Shiny and New 安宇:  Some exceptions for last names include "Smitty" for *Smith*, and "Mick" or "Mac" for names starting with "Mc" or "Mac".  The latter may be considered by some to be an ethnic slur against people from Ireland or Scotland.

Comment: My last name is Fogleman and a lot of people call me Fogle.

Comment: First names can be shortened to nicknames and used in a more formal settings. Last names are never shortened in formal settings.

Comment: OP should be *very* careful about shortening any part of a person's name unless the person specifically asks him to. When you are introduced to someone, and they tell you their name, *that* is normally what they expect you to call them. Any variation should only be introduced with caution, *even if you hear other people use a short form*. It's not uncommon for someone to have a familiar name used *only* by very close friends/family, where they would (quite rightly, IMHO) take offense if a relative social newcomer used the term.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off-topic: *when* to shorten a person's surname is an issue of interpersonal/social skills and is culturally defined.

Comment: The great Frank Robinson of the Cincinnati Reds and (later) Baltimore Orioles was known by the nickname "Robbie"—but that was just a nickname and would not have been used on formal documents or in a formal context.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Shortened versions of surnames (last names) are often used as nicknames in English-speaking countries, but normally by people on very familiar terms with the person and therefore not in quite the same way as Robert might be shortened to Bob or Steven to Steve.

In my experience (predominantly British English) longer surnames such as Robinson and Brightman might be shortened to Robbo or Brighty or even extended from one sylable to two with the addition of an "o" or "y", e.g. Brown to Browny.

I would emphasise that this isn't something that would happen outside relatively close circles of friends, teammates or colleagues.

Comment: Such shortening is [a recognized and documented phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_%22-er%22)

Comment: You forgot a circle: friends, teammates, colleagues, ***or enemies/haters***. I doubt George W. Bush’s friends call him _Dubya_, and I'm entirely certain that any acquaintance of Lord Voldemort who called him _Voldy_ to his face as a nickname would not live long to tell the tale.

Comment: "...But using a modification of a last name as a nickname, though it can happen, is definitely much much less frequent than mods of the first name or other choices."

Answer (score 5):

Shortened names are also known as **nicknames**. They're generally casual, shorter versions of a person's first name (Like Andy for Andrew), though they can be assigned based on features or characteristics, as well (Shorty, for example).

A nickname could be taken from a last name; it's feasible that George Macintosh, say, could be called 'Mac' by his friends.

There is no other reason that I can think of in which a last name would be shortened. It is not standard practice and could in fact be quite confusing!

Comment: Nicknames are not always shortened names. Although they usually are derived somehow from a name they can also be derived from some other characteristic e.g. a tall person may have the nickname 'Lanky'

Comment: I'm pretty sure I made that clear; see the Shorty example.

Comment: Technically, a shortened name is a *diminutive*.

Comment: @onomatomaniak - you did make that clear, apologies for that. However, your first sentence implies that nicknames are synonymous with shortened names, so people with short attention spans (like me!) may misunderstand your point.

Comment: Other applicable terms include *hypocoristic* and *pet name*. The definitions tend to be somewhat fluid; one linguist may use hypocoristic exactly where another would use diminutive, or vice versa.

Comment: Another example is [Chelsey "Sully" Sullenberger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chesley_Sullenberger).

Comment: @Marthaª Much belated, but no—a shortened name is not necessarily a diminutive. Diminutives are a semantic category that involve adding an affix to create a word that means ‘small(er) X’, usually _-y/-ie_ in English. _Bob_ from _Robert_ is not a diminutive, for example, though _Andy_ could perhaps be considered a diminutive of _Andrew_, and _Johnny_ definitely is one of _John_. Spanish nicknames are very frequently clear diminutives (_Juanito, Carlosito_, etc.), and non-shortened female names are often diminutives of male names (_Juanita, Henrietta, Wilhelmina_, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Only colloquially and among friends. Sometimes the name is lengthened in such circumstances, For example, 'Jones' can become 'Jonesy'.

Answer (score 2):

Nicknames come into use either because the original name is long and/or cumbersome and the nickname is shorter and/or catchier, or as a term of endearment.

Answer (score 1):

The general rule is ask someone if they mind being called "X" before you refer to them as "X".

In various situtations, it may be normal to commonly refer to people principally by last name, such as in certain schools, military, sports, etc.

In such cases, a person's last name could easily be nick-named in time. From my experience, this occurs when the last name is long, complicated, exotic, or cool sounding.

Answer (score -1):

My family name is Clifford.  My dad was always called "Cliff" or "Cliffy" at work and so when I grew up, I would also "shorten" my last name as a option for what ppl could call me.  However, I didn't realize that this practice is fairly uncommon in the US in 2021, and people sometimes don't know if my last name is Clifford or Cliff.  To me, it's so obvious, but I guess if you aren't used to it happening, it is confusing.

Perhaps it's because Clifford is also a first name, which would lend to a natural nickname in "Cliff" or "Cliffy" and people just did that to my dad.  I also wonder if it's a generational thing--ppl's names lacked the variety of today and I think that would make ppl more likely to use and be creative with nicknames.  Today, it's more common for a person to ask to be called by his or her full name (William instead of Bill), so ppl would be less likely to use nicknames anyways, first or last name.

Comment: Please use proper English, in deference to the nature of our site; "ppl" is unacceptable. Please note that EL&U isn't a discussion forum: we're not interested in personal opinions. Instead, we're looking for *detailed, authoritative answers* supported by evidence, preferably hyperlinked to a published source. For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U [Tour]. :-)